# Need help understanding while loops

Tags: c

Let's say that we have a very simple code that begins like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    int x;

    printf("Num here: ");
    c = getchar();
    x = 0;

    while (c!=EOF) {
        x = c - 48; //to convert x from ASCII
```

In this program, I'm trying to get the user to type a number (ex. 42) and am trying to add the ones digit to the tens (and to the hundreds, etc.); I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how you can get the while loop to go back to the loop until the end of the number.

So, I need a lot of help understanding how I can get the loop to read until the end of the character, read the char input the user puts in as a number (42), and then, treat the numbers individually using just getchar().

Comment: `getchar()` doesn't return a `char`. Your code won't work correctly.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But the `char` is also an integer type and eventually it will end up storing integers only , also as far as ASCII is concerned the `getchar()` won't get too far than returning 127 , so it is safe for storage too. ain't it?

Comment: @PHI: Who said that `getchar()` was restricted to ASCII?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am talking in this context. Here user makes use of ASCII. Does it really make difference when we are only concerned about ASCII?

Comment: Assuming that a program will only receive what the programmer wants it to receive is the first step towards creating a brittle piece of crap.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes , exactly I understand :)

Answer (score 8):

Normally, you'd use:

```
int c;  // Because getchar() returns an int, not a char
int x = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (isdigit(c))
        x = x * 10 + (c - '0');
    else
        ...
}
```

This reads a character each time it reaches the top of the loop.  You get the loop to go back by running into the brace at the end of the loop (or, occasionally, by using a `continue` statement). You might exit the loop with a `break`, for example if you read some character that can't be part of a number.

If the user types `42` (followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>), then you first read `c == '4'` and then `c == '2'` and then you read newline `'\n'`.  For every digit from `'0'` to `'9'`, `digit - '0'` yields the number corresponding to the digit.  The newline can't be part of the number, so you either put it back with `ungetc(c, stdin)` or break the loop when you've read it.

Beware of overflow if the user types 43219876543 where you expected just 42 (and `int` is a 32-bit quantity).

You could write the loop condition as:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c))
```

or even:

```
while (isdigit(c = getchar()))
```

I'd be extremely reluctant to actually put the latter into production code but it is, in theory, safe.

---

> How could I treat each number individually so that I can use the entirety of the numbers later on? So that if the user types `10 20 30`, I can multiply `10` by `20`, then (`10*20`) by `30`?

Wheels within wheels — or loops within loops. You'll need to specify your criteria a bit. If the user types `1` you want the answer `1`; if they type `1 2`, you want `2`; if they type `1 2 3`, you want `6`; and so on (where these are all the numbers on a single line of input). You'll need an outer loop that skips over blanks and tabs, then uses the inner loop to read a number, and then multiplies the current product (initial value `1`) by the new number, and after the outer loop, you'll print the product. This will print `1` for an empty line; maybe that doesn't matter (and maybe it does).

Here's some code that approximates what is appropriate:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        int product = 1;
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        {
            while (isspace(c))
                c = getchar();
            int number = 0;
            while (isdigit(c))
            {
                number = number * 10 + (c - '0');
                c = getchar();
            }
            printf("Number:  %d\n", number);
            product *= number;
        }
        printf("Product: %d\n", product);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried a version with a slightly different 'skip' loop:

```
            while (c != EOF && c != '\n' && !isdigit(c))
                c = getchar();
```

Both work OK on sane inputs.  Empty lines are treated as end of input; lines containing blanks are not.  If you input `1a2b3c` with the second condition, you will get the output `0`; with the first, you get an infinite loop.  There is no overflow protection; don't try doing factorial 20 and expect the correct answer (with 32-bit `int`).  Tweak to your heart's content.

Comment: But the char is also an integer type and eventually it will end up storing integers only , also as far as ASCII is concerned the getchar() won't get too far than returning 127 , so it is safe for storage too. ain't it?

Comment: It is not safe to store the result of `getchar()` in a `char` because it returns an `int`, not a `char`. To be precise, `getchar()` can return every value corresponding to an `unsigned char`, plus an extra distinct value EOF which is guaranteed to be negative. If you store the result of `getchar()` in a plain `char` and then compare with EOF, one of two bugs occurs. Either plain `char` is unsigned and the `c == EOF` condition is never true, or plain `char` is signed and then a valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is misinterpreted as EOF.

Comment: EOF is defined `-1` in `stdio.h` ( atleast that's what C primer  has to say about it) and getchar() returns EOF when the end of file is reached ...... If we don't talk about unicode for now and just ASCII then negative value won't pose a problem ? Actually , I am very confused about it. Yet ,its a fact that so many books use `char` to store the return of `getchar()`

Comment: @PHI: You live in a world of 7+ billion people, most of whom do not use ASCII. Learn to program in 21st Century C and accept that characters use at minimum the full range of 8-bit values.  Don't pretend you're dealing with ASCII. The most common value of EOF is indeed `-1`. However, all the standard says is that it is negative; it does not stipulate that it is `-1` and assuming it is `-1` is unwise and pointless. If you store `-1` in an `unsigned char`, it will never compare equal to EOF (because the character value will be 0xFF, and 0xFF is not -1). _[...Continued...]_

Comment: _[...Continuation...]_ On many machines much of the time, you will get away with abusing the rules I've laid out for you.  Then you'll spend æons debugging a problem from your important new customer from Turkey, who ends up suing you for broken software that doesn't work properly for him. If you follow the rules outlined here, you won't run into that problem (though there are others you'll have to worry about in due course — Turkish is a fun language). Just remember the simple rule: **`getchar()` returns an `int` and the value must not be stored in a `char`!** (until it's proven it's not EOF).

Comment: hahaha that's an amazing explanation ... feeling enlightened thanks :) :) :) and ah!! a miniscule +1 for you .

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!  I have one more question: how could I treat each number individually so that I can use the entirety of the numbers later on?  So that if the user types 10 20 30, I can multiply 10 by 20, then (10*20) by 30?  My main confusion with this part of the problem is that I don't understand how you can treat these numbers separately by using just getchar() (esp. when it's much simpler with scanf()).

Comment: Wheels within wheels — or loops within loops. You'll need to specify your criteria a bit. If the user types `1` you want the answer `1`; if they type `1 2`, you want `2`; if they type `1 2 3`, you want `6`; and so on (where these are all the numbers on a single line of input). You'll need an outer loop that skips over blanks and tabs, then uses the inner loop to read a number, and then multiplies the current product (initial value `1`) by the new number, and after the outer loop, you'll print the product. This will print `1` for an empty line; maybe that doesn't matter (and maybe it does).

Comment: So would it looks something like:

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to leave the sentence hanging, I just forgot to edit it more.  Is there any way that I can do it by including only #include <stdio.h>? I'm currently trying: 

    while (c!='\n') {
        while (c!=' ') {
            k = (k*10) + c - 48;
            c=getchar();
            sum+=k;

            if (c==' ') {
                c = getchar();
            }

Comment: Of course: you can write your own variant of `isdigit()` and any other macro like that.  Don't use `48`; use `'0'`.  The numeric value is the same, but the clarity of meaning from using `'0'` is vastly superior to the 'magic number' 48.

Answer (score 1):

Your code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<ctype.h>
int main() {
    int c;//getchar() returns integer
    int x;

    printf("Num here: ");

    x=0;    
    //As @Jonathan Leffler  suggested ,  
    //usage of while loop like this is very helpful the moment you press Enter loop breaks.  

    while (isdigit(c = getchar())) //isdigit is a function from ctype.h checks for Entered character is digit or not
        x = x*10 + c - 48; //here '0'==48   
    printf("%d",x);  
    }
```

when you enter 42

```
loop rotates two times for c==4 and c==2
c==4 
x=0*10+'4'-48 //here '4'==52 ==>  x=0+52-48  ==>x=4
c==2
x=4*10+'2'-48 //here '2'==50 ==> x=40+50-48 ==>x=42
```

to add ones digits to tens and then hundreds ...  if you want to add digits in input number use this below while loop

```
int sum=0,num;
//read num
while(num>0)
{
sum=sum+num%10; //get the last digit and add to sum
num=num/10; //reduce last digit of num
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in character by character and convert that to a numeral using the while loop in Jonathan's answer. Every time you read a numeral, simply multiple your current sum by 10, and add the number. That way by the time you read the last numeral and add it in, you'll have the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the way we think a problem should be solved, can be solved in a different method when all of the languages capabilities are considered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Num here: ");
    scanf("%d", x);

}
```

implements the same functionality as your program.